# Using aspnet_regiis in production server

Tags: encryption, asp.net

I want to use aspnet_regiis to encrypt sections of my web.config in production environment. As per my understanding one need .NET command prompt to run the command to encrypt.

How can we achieve this if we have only .NET framework installed in production and not Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Having the .NET framework installed should be sufficient. The aspnet_regiis can be found under the folder for the .NET version that your application is using.
For .NET 2.0 you will find it under:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\`